# Can't store array: TypeError htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, typeerror, laravel-8

So, i had problems with storing datas from a form which contains array in it.
Here's my create.blade.php view, and i'm using JS to make dynamic input to create another input based on the same div:

```
<form action="{{ route('grading_sheets.store') }}" method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
                    @csrf
                {{-- another inputs here --}}

                    <div class="attitude_container">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="point_id" class="form-label">Nilai Sikap <span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <select name="point_id[]" type="text"
                                        class="form-control select2 @error('point_id') is-invalid   @enderror"
                                        value="{{ old('point_id') }}" required autocomplete="point_id">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>- Pilih Nilai Sikap -</option>
                                        @foreach ($points as $point)
                                        <option value="{{$point->id}}"
                                            {{ old('point_id') == $point->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            {{$point->attitude_point}}
                                        </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    @error('point_id')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                    @enderror
                                    @else
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Mohon isikan nilai sikap
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nilai <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="grade" name="grade[]"
                                        class="form-control @error('grade') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        placeholder="Masukkan nilai" value="{{ old('grade') }}" required>
                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    @error('grade')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                    @enderror
                                    @else
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Mohon isikan nilai
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Predikat <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 @error('predicate') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        name="predicate[]" value="{{ old('predicate') }}" required>
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>- Pilih Predikat -</option>
                                        <option value="A" {{ old('predicate') == 'A' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            A</option>
                                        <option value="B" {{ old('predicate') == 'B' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            B</option>
                                        <option value="C" {{ old('predicate') == 'C' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            C</option>
                                        <option value="D" {{ old('predicate') == 'D' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            D</option>
                                        <option value="E" {{ old('predicate') == 'E' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            E</option>
                                        <option value="F" {{ old('predicate') == 'F' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            F</option>
                                        <option value="Kompeten" {{ old('predicate') == 'Kompeten' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            Kompeten</option>
                                    </select>
                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    @error('predicate')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        The predicate field is required.
                                    </div>
                                    @enderror
                                    @else
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Mohon isikan predikat
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary add_attitude_form"><i
                                        class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <div class="competency_container">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="competency_point" class="form-label">Nilai Kompetensi <span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <select id="competency_point" name="competency_point[]" type="text"
                                        class="form-control select2 @error('competency_point') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        value="{{ old('competency_point') }}" required autocomplete="competency_point">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>- Pilih Kompetensi -</option>
                                        @foreach ($points as $point)
                                        <option value="{{$point->competency_point}}"
                                            {{ old('competency_point') == $point->competency_point ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            {{$point->competency_point}}
                                        </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    @error('competency_point')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                    @enderror
                                    @else
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Mohon isikan nilai kompetensi
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nilai <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="grade" name="grade[]"
                                        class="form-control @error('grade') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        placeholder="Masukkan nilai" value="{{ old('grade') }}" required>
                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    @error('grade')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                    @enderror
                                    @else
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Mohon isikan nilai
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Predikat <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 @error('predicate') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        name="predicate[]" id="predicate" value="{{ old('predicate') }}" required>
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>- Pilih Predikat -</option>
                                        <option value="A" {{ old('predicate') == 'A' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            A</option>
                                        <option value="B" {{ old('predicate') == 'B' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            B</option>
                                        <option value="C" {{ old('predicate') == 'C' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            C</option>
                                        <option value="D" {{ old('predicate') == 'D' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            D</option>
                                        <option value="E" {{ old('predicate') == 'E' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            E</option>
                                        <option value="F" {{ old('predicate') == 'F' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            F</option>
                                        <option value="Kompeten" {{ old('predicate') == 'Kompeten' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            Kompeten</option>
                                    </select>
                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    @error('predicate')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        The predicate field is required.
                                    </div>
                                    @enderror
                                    @else
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Mohon isikan predikat
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary add_competency_form"><i
                                        class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <div class="float-right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Tambah</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

That JS dynamic function:

```
<script>
    // Bagian div attitude

    $(document).ready(function () {
      let max_fields = 8
      let wrapper = $('.attitude_container')
      let add_button = $('.add_attitude_form')

      let x = 1
      $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (x < max_fields) {
          x++
          $(wrapper).append(
            `<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="point_id" class="form-label">Nilai Sikap <span
                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <select name="point_id[]" type="text"
                                        class="form-control select2 @error('point_id') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        value="{{ old('point_id') }}" required autocomplete="point_id">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>- Pilih Nilai Sikap -</option>
                                        @foreach ($points as $point)
                                        <option value="{{$point->id}}"
                                            {{ old('point_id') == $point->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            {{$point->attitude_point}}
                                        </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    @error('point_id')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                    @enderror
                                    @else
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Mohon isikan nilai sikap
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nilai <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="number" id="grade" name="grade[]"
                                        class="form-control @error('grade') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        placeholder="Masukkan nilai" value="{{ old('grade') }}" required>
                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    @error('grade')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $message }}
                                    </div>
                                    @enderror
                                    @else
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Mohon isikan nilai
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Predikat <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 @error('predicate') is-invalid @enderror"
                                        name="predicate[]" value="{{ old('predicate') }}" required>
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>- Pilih Predikat -</option>
                                        <option value="A" {{ old('predicate') == 'A' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            A</option>
                                        <option value="B" {{ old('predicate') == 'B' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            B</option>
                                        <option value="C" {{ old('predicate') == 'C' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            C</option>
                                        <option value="D" {{ old('predicate') == 'D' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            D</option>
                                        <option value="E" {{ old('predicate') == 'E' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            E</option>
                                        <option value="F" {{ old('predicate') == 'F' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            F</option>
                                        <option value="Kompeten" {{ old('predicate') == 'Kompeten' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            Kompeten</option>
                                    </select>
                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                    @error('predicate')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        The predicate field is required.
                                    </div>
                                    @enderror
                                    @else
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Mohon isikan predikat
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-danger delete_attitude"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>`
          ) // nambah div competency
        } else {
          alert('Telah melebihi batas')
        }
      })

      $(wrapper).on('click', '.delete_attitude', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).closest('.d-flex').remove()
        x--
      })
    })

    // Bagian div competency

    $(document).ready(function () {
      let max_fields = 8
      let wrapper = $('.competency_container')
      let add_button = $('.add_competency_form')

      let x = 1
      $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (x < max_fields) {
          x++
          $(wrapper).append(
            `<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="competency_point" class="form-label">Nilai Kompetensi <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <select id="competency_point" name="competency_point[]" type="text"
                                    class="form-control select2 @error('competency_point') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    value="{{ old('competency_point') }}" required autocomplete="competency_point">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>- Pilih Kompetensi -</option>
                                    @foreach ($points as $point)
                                    <option value="{{$point->competency_point}}"
                                        {{ old('competency_point') == $point->competency_point ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                        {{$point->competency_point}}
                                    </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                @error('competency_point')
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {{ $message }}
                                </div>
                                @enderror
                                @else
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Mohon isikan nilai kompetensi
                                </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nilai <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <input type="number" id="grade" name="grade[]"
                                    class="form-control @error('grade') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    placeholder="Masukkan nilai" value="{{ old('grade') }}" required>
                                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                @error('grade')
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {{ $message }}
                                </div>
                                @enderror
                                @else
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Mohon isikan nilai
                                </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Predikat <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <select class="form-control select2 @error('predicate') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    name="predicate[]" id="predicate" value="{{ old('predicate') }}" required>
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>- Pilih Predikat -</option>
                                    <option value="A" {{ old('predicate') == 'A' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                        A</option>
                                    <option value="B" {{ old('predicate') == 'B' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                        B</option>
                                    <option value="C" {{ old('predicate') == 'C' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                        C</option>
                                    <option value="D" {{ old('predicate') == 'D' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                        D</option>
                                    <option value="E" {{ old('predicate') == 'E' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                        E</option>
                                    <option value="F" {{ old('predicate') == 'F' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                        F</option>
                                    <option value="Kompeten" {{ old('predicate') == 'Kompeten' ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                        Kompeten</option>
                                </select>
                                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                @error('predicate')
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    The predicate field is required.
                                </div>
                                @enderror
                                @else
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Mohon isikan predikat
                                </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon btn-danger delete_competency"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
          ) // nambah div competency
        } else {
          alert('Telah melebihi batas')
        }
      })

      $(wrapper).on('click', '.delete_competency', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).closest('.d-flex').remove()
        x--
      })
    })
</script>
```

Store method in controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            "student_id"            => "required|integer",
            "nis"                   => "required|integer",
            "class"                 => "required|string",
            "major"                 => "required|not_in:0",
            "point_id"              => "required|array",
            "point_id.*"            => "integer",
            "competency_point"      => "required|array",
            "competency_point.*"    => "string",
            "grade"                 => "required|array",
            "grade.*"               => "integer",
            "predicate"             => "required|array",
            "predicate.*"           => "integer",
        ]);

        foreach ($request->point_id as $pointId) {
            GradingSheet::create([
                "student_id"       => $request->student_id,
                "nis"              => $request->nis,
                "class"            => $request->class,
                "major"            => $request->major,
                "point_id"         => $pointId,
                "competency_point" => $request->competency_point,
                "grade"            => $request->grade,
                "predicate"        => $request->predicate,
            ]);
        }

        return redirect("dashboard/grading_sheets")->with(
            "success",
            "Tambah data siswa berhasil!"
        );
```

And here's data arrays when i use dd:

```
array:8 [▼
  "student_id" => "1"
  "class" => "12"
  "major" => "Pengembangan Perangkat Lunak dan Gim"
  "point_id" => array:7 [▶]
  "grade" => array:15 [▶]
  "predicate" => array:15 [▶]
  "competency_point" => array:8 [▶]
]
```

I tried to make foreach to loop all the array but as the result i got that error, how can I store these array datas without getting any trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**
I'm making those array inputs with brackets like thise: name=grade[], and use json encode in controller:

```
$createGradingSheet = GradingSheet::create([
            'student_id'       => $request->student_id,
            'nis'              => $request->nis,
            'class'            => $request->class,
            'major'            => $request->major,
            'attitude_point'   => json_encode($request->attitude_point),
            'competency_point' => json_encode($request->competency_point),
            'grade'            => json_encode($request->grade),
            'predicate'        => json_encode($request->predicate),          
        ]);
```

And i added spesific column with json type like this:

```
$table->json('attitude_point')->nullable(); 
            $table->json('competency_point')->nullable();
            $table->json('grade')->nullable();
            $table->json('predicate')->nullable();
```